# How to install postgresql 9.6 on MacOS 12.1 Monterey, Intel chip?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, macos-monterey

I'm using MacOS Monterey 12.1 Intel chip, and Postgresql 9.6 installation from https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads

When I run EDB installation, it fails with below message

> The database cluster initialization failed

After a couple hours for researching, I found that the installation will execute the `${postgres_home}/installer/server/initcluster.sh`,
then the `initcluster.sh` will execute `${postgres_home}/bin/postgres -V`.

But the `bin/postgres -V` failed with message: `zsh: segmentation fault  ./postgres -V`

Then, the `initcluster.sh` will be stopped and there is no database cluster to be installed.

Can anyone help me to install Postgresql9.6 on MacOS 12.1?
Or I must wait for EBD's update?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you install from source?

Comment: Why install an unsupported and discontinued version to begin with?

Comment: Got the same message attempting to install 14.1?  Thoughts?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I installed from source yesterday. Thanks for your advice. Upvoted.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name 
base on my business requirement, it"s not easy to upgrade to a higher version.

Comment: @justdan0227
I have contacted to EDB, but doesn't reply. So I installed from source.